# How can I open a file in Batch without focusing on it?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm using the `start` command to open a .mp3 or .wav file in wmplayer along with other certain events in a Batch program I'm writing. It works perfectly, and is accompanied by `TASKKILL /IM wmplayer.exe` to stop the program when the user goes to the next screen of the application. The only thing that could make it work more smoothly is if the program would open in the background, so the user doesn't have to click back into CMD. Is there any way to open the sound effect in wmplayer without switching focus over to wmplayer, and furthermore remaining selected into CMD? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the original batch file open an alternate one after opening your wmplayer.exe to put the alternate on top. From there you could program the alternate to do all the same things your original file would do.

For example your main file's code could be:

```
    @echo off
    title Yourtitle
    start wmplayer.exe
    start AltBatch.bat
    exit
```

And your alternate (AltBatch.bat):

```
    @echo off
    title YourTitle
    :: (Your code here)
```

Or, simply put this would be the layered order on screen:
Original > wmplayer.exe > Alternate

Comment: I thought about that, but the console executes the sound file at various parts deep within the code, so running and alternate code would be complicated since there are many pending circumstances and variables. It would also require anywhere from 5 to an infinite number of alto are batch files.

Answer (score 0):

So let me know if this code can did the trick or not ?
You just change the path of your sound !

```
@echo off
Title Playing sound on the background while executing some commands
set Soundfile=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/feeling.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%Soundfile%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
ping www.google.com
ping www.stackoverflow.com
tracert www.google.com
tracert www.stackoverflow.com
pause
```

Comment: This looks promising! Unfortunately, I'm not incredible at Batch. I've made a few projects but I don't understand the language too well. You'll have to explain what's going on here. What do I need to change for this script to work on my files?

Comment: @tjbushra ==> This code show you how to play sound on the background while executing some commands ! so you can play sound online or offline just you change one thing on this code the path of the Soundfile that's all !
Just give a try on it,because, i changed the soundfile path online and i think, you should listen to the sound now !